# How to get date to auto refresh?

Tags: javascript, date, setinterval

I am trying to get a date to refresh on a page so I don't have to go and manually refresh it everyday. I have this code in place, but it doesn't seem to be working. The date displays, but it doesn't update when the day changes. For reference, this is being used on a BrightSign display. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm kind of a JavaScript beginner so nothing too complex :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
function clockTick()    {
   currentTime = new Date();
   month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
   day = currentTime.getDate();
   year = currentTime.getFullYear();
   setInterval(clockTick, 1000);
   return (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
}
document.write(clockTick());
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: [First you do not use document.write.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice), second, learn about setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: If you want the date to refresh, you have to poll it with an interval and actually change it when the day changes. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:call `clockTick()`  from outside.

```js
 function clockTick()    {
       currentTime = new Date();
       month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
       day = currentTime.getDate();
       year = currentTime.getFullYear();
      // alert("hi");
      document.getElementById('date').innerHTML=month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
    
    setInterval(function(){clockTick();}, 1000);//setInterval(clockTick, 1000); will also work
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to take the `setInterval` out of the function and set the time on the page inside the function so that it refreshes every second:

```js
function clockTick() {
  var currentTime = new Date(),
      month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1,
      day = currentTime.getDate(),
      year = currentTime.getFullYear(),
      hours = currentTime.getHours(),
      minutes = currentTime.getMinutes(),
      seconds = currentTime.getSeconds(),
      text = (month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
  // here we get the element with the id of "date" and change the content to the text variable we made above
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = text;
}

// here we run the clockTick function every 1000ms (1 second)
setInterval(clockTick, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="date"></span>
```

Comment: Feel free to select the answer as correct if you are satisfied =P