# How I reload div for javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reload div content, the results I found on the web didn't work for me. Help me
My Code;

```js
var x = new Date();
document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML=x;
```

```html
<div id="refresh"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. The contents of the div with id `refresh` is replaced by the current date. Did you expect it to do something else?

Comment: I know right now I'm trying to show the date. But I want to renew this process constantly

Comment: You could do the same thing at an interval. Look into [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) for that.

Comment: Does this maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526857/how-to-get-date-to-auto-refresh

Answer (score 1):

So your code should look like this:

```
setInterval(refresh, 1000);

function refresh() {
    var x = new Date();
    document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML = x;
}

refresh();
```

you need to call the function continuously. It didn't work because in your code it only calls it once.

Answer (score 0):

As my understood, you want to show system date on your html dom, right?

if so, you have to use some button, or you can use setInterval function. For example:

```
<div id="refresh">
</div>
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    var x = new Date();
    document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML = x;
  }, 300);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine and working I have checked Please check your Javascript library reference

Here is the working code

```
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('refresh').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<div id="refresh"> 
</div>
```

For reload, u can use setInterval

```
<html>
<body>
     
<div id="refresh"> 
</div>
        
<script>
//When the document is loaded
document.addEventListener("load", myTimer);
//subsequent calls
setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer(){
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
}
</script>   

</body>
</html>
```